# How to covert giant Ape file -> multiple FLAC files

Tags: conversion, flac

I have a CD that has been converted to one giant ape file (all songs in one ape file).  How can I covert this into multiple FLAC files (one FLAC per song)?

Comment: I'd like to know this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found http://www.medieval.it/cuesplitter-pc/menu-id-71.html#twoj_fragment1-3

This seems to split the ape file up into multiple files and then CDEX to convert...

Comment: Cuesplitter works great!

Comment: Cuesplitter is the best!  Then use Monkeys to decompress the files  http://www.monkeysaudio.com/

Comment: Yeah, I used CDEX for the conversion, but same result I think...

Answer (score 1):

Foobar2000 can do this too.